# Powershell : How to allow for example only 2 character to be in a variable?

Tags: variables, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

i am still quiete new to scripting and everything. I liked the GUI from this custom T[Custom Text Box](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx) where you can basicially store variables you entered before.

Now I have an input box with 2 text fields and I can store Whatever I want!
I need a way to allow the user only to put in 2 characters not more. Or for example allow him only integers. Since my english isnt the best and my used terms didn't fit into google I guess I was unable to find a way to manage that. So whats a good approach specify my variables?

I thought about property lenght greater than 2 or something, but is there are better way? or easier ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Validating` event TextBox provices to validate the contents. Create an event handler for the event and check that contents are what you'd expect. Here's [an example](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f8b29a84-007c-4a86-ba46-33f3a67137f8/validate-textbox-with-regular-expressions?forum=winserverpowershell) how to use regex to validate textbox input on a Powershell script.